# Is it possible to ssh into the IKS worker nodes deployed on vpc2 infa?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, iks

1. If a **K8s cluster** is deployed on **IBM VPC2 infrastructure** then Is it possible to ssh into the worker nodes? I have enabled Public Gateway but I'm not sure if I can do the ssh using the public IP mentioned in the public gateway?
2. Also Is it possible to assign a public IP to every worker node? Like a floating IP for every worker node?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the managed offering of IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service (IKS) or Red Hat OpenShift (ROKS), then SSH access is disabled by default.

Public Gateways enabled on the VPC Subnets of your worker nodes are for establishing outbound connections to the internet from the nodes contained within that subnet.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-vpc-subnets#vpc_basics_pgw

Likewise, if you're using either of the managed offerings mentioned above, you have no access to the actual VPC VSI worker nodes through your VPC infrastructure, and can not assign public IP's to them.

You can however enable a public service endpoint during VPC cluster creation that will allow services unable to communicate over the Private Service Endpoint to still work over the Public Service Endpoint.